# A question of "elementary imsets" in an ADMG

Tags: probability, graphical-model, conditional-independence

In [The m-connecting imset and factorization for ADMG models] (https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2207.08963), it was mentioned the notation of an "elementary imset". The definition of elementary imset is:

> If $\langle a,b \mid C \rangle \in J(V)$, then the corresponding elementary imset $u_{\langle a,b \mid C \rangle}: P(V) \rightarrow Z$ is an imset defined:
> $$u_{\langle a,b \mid C \rangle} = \delta_{abC} +\delta_C - \delta_{aC} -\delta_{bC} .$$
> Where $\delta$ is an identifier.

Then in this paper, it was mentioned that:

> Elementary imsets were designed to represent statements of conditional independence in this manner.

**Question:** Why can it represent probability conditional independence? And how do you understand it?